# Como puedo cargar un modulo de angular4 en un angular1?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

Buen dia.

Como podria cargar un modulo que tengo en un app web con angular4, en una aplicacion con angular1?

Answer (score 1):

de manera directa no se puede. Angular 2 rompió la compatibilidad con AngularJS desde su lanzamiento.
Aunque se pueden generar unos adaptadores para utilizar componentes de Angular 4 en AngularJS, esto no es lo más idóneo debido a su complejidad y dificultad de mantenimiento.

[Tutorial Adaptadores Angular](https://hackernoon.com/angular-v4-hybrid-upgrade-application-73d5afba1e01)